# Write Text String to Table via CurrentDb.Execute strSql

Tags: ms-access, vba

I can not translate what is read into strTextLine into the individual "VALUES" that SQL is looking for in the CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError.

```
Public Function ReadTextFile()

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objTextStream As Object
Dim strTextLine As String
Dim strInputFileName As String, strSql As String, strLine As String, x As Integer

strInputFileName = "F:\Test\Input.txt"
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objTextStream = objFSO.OpenTextFile(strInputFileName)

Do While Not (objTextStream.AtEndOfStream)

strTextLine = objTextStream.ReadLine

    If Left(strTextLine, 4) = "1RUN" Then
        x = 0
    Else
        If x < 9 Then
        Else
            Debug.Print strTextLine, Values
            'strSql = "INSERT INTO tmp_tbl_load_loc_match ( field1, field 2, etc .. )Values ( ???"
            'CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError
        End If
    End If

x = x + 1

Loop

objTextStream.Close
Set objFSO = Nothing
Set objTextStream = Nothing

End Function
```

Comment: Eh... I have no clue what you mean with  "can not translate what is read into the string". Please clarify. What do you want to insert, what is going wrong?

Comment: Your strSql is only the first part of a complete SQL command. All the values are missing. So read up on SQL syntax.

Comment: I know the values are blank that is where I am stumped.  How do I segment (translate) strTextLine into the values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrote a function to parse the string into individual fields and then appended to the VALUES portion of the SQL.

strSql = funInsertSql(strTextLine)
                CurrentDb.Execute strSql, dbFailOnError

I am a part time programmer.  Would have though someone that does this all the time could have helped or at least engaged in some dialog to help resolve.